# SQL Query Help

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

Am Using SQL SERVER - 2000

Table Structure

```
CARDEVENTDATE       CARDEVENTTIME   CARDNO
20090224            92007           485
20090224            92345           321
20090225            163932          168
20090225            164630          471
20090225            165027          488
20090225            165137          247
20090225            165147          519
20090225            165715          518
20090225            165749          331
20090303            162059          240
20090303            162723          518
20090303            155029          386
20090303            155707          441
20090303    162824  331
```

`Cardeventdate` and `Cardeventtime` - nvarchar data type
Date and Time is separate column

I want to get a data between

Yesterday 03:00:01 AM to today 03:00:00 AM
Day before yesterday 03:00:01 AM to yesterday 03:00:00 AM
So On……..

I tried the below mentioned query’s

```
Select Cardno, cardeventdate, min(cardeventtime), max(cardeventtime) 
from table 
where cardeventtime between 030001 to 030000

Select Cardno, Cardeventdate, Min(cardeventtime), max(cardeventtime) 
from table 
where Cardeventtime >030001 and  Cardeventtime < 030000
```

Nothing displayed in the result because it is taking today time from 03.00 am to 03.01am

```
Select Cardno, Cardeventdate, min (cardeventtime), max (cardeventtime) 
from table 
where cardeventtime < 030000 and cardeventtime > previous day time – query help
```

Exactly I need yesterday 03.00.01 am to today 03.00.00 am data’s, Day before yesterday 03.00.01 am to yesterday 03.00.00 am data’s  …………………. So on

I need the sql query for the above condition. Can any one help me?

(edit: I need the date from yesterday morning to this morning, up to 03.00am)

Comment: You will need to combine the date and time columns into a SQL datetime (you can do this within your query, without changing the tables) to be able to do any useful comparisons (across days at least, like you want to).

Comment: please edit your post using '>' at the beginning of lines for blockquote, or indent 4 spaces for code blocks

Comment: first of all what are those MIN() and MAX() doing in your queries?

Comment: I'm guessing from the wording what you actually want is all the data grouped by each day but rather than going midnight to midnight you want the data grouped from 3am to 3am? is this correct?

Comment: that's what I asked myself when I saw those MIN() and MAX() calls...

Comment: @Joe: Not modifying the table would make any kinds of indexes unusable. Probably a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The below is testet on SQL Server 2005 Express. If SQL Server 2000 does not have Common Table Expressions (CTE), a view could be used instead to produce the same as 'cteTbl' would. And I do hope that SQL Server 2000 supports the CASE-WHEN-END.

The idea I use in this, is to extend the hours a day have, from 24h to 27h (+3), but only where [CardEventTime] is less or equal to 03:00:00 (24h) I add 24h and to [CardEventDate] subtract 1d.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  CardEventDate INTEGER
  ,CardEventTime INTEGER
  ,CardNo INTEGER
)

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090224,92007,485)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090224,92345,321)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090225,163932,168)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090225,164630,471)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090225,165027,488)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090225,165137,247)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090225,165147,519)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090225,165715,518)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090225,165749,331)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090303,162059,240)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090303,162723,518)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090303,155029,386)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090303,155707,441)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090303,162824,331)

-- Some boundary test values, for only one cardno.
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090330,235959,331)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090331,000000,331)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090331,025959,331)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090331,030000,331)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090331,030001,331)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090331,235959,331)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090401,000000,331)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090401,025959,331)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090401,030000,331)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (20090401,030001,331)
go

WITH 
cteTbl AS (
  SELECT
    CardEventDate,
    CardEventTime,
    CardNo,
    CASE 
      WHEN CardEventTime <= 30000 THEN dateadd(dd, -1, cast(CardEventDate AS VARCHAR))
      WHEN CardEventTime > 30000 THEN cast(cast(CardEventDate AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME)
    END AS ShiftedCardEventDate,
    CASE 
      WHEN CardEventTime <= 30000 THEN CardEventTime+240000
      WHEN CardEventTime > 30000 THEN CardEventTime
    END AS ShiftedCardEventTime
  FROM tbl
)
SELECT
  CardNo, 
  ShiftedCardEventDate,
  --min(shiftedCardEventTime) as [MinCardEventTime], 
  --max(shiftedCardEventTime) as [MaxCardEventTime],
  right('000000'+cast((min(shiftedCardEventTime) % 240000) AS VARCHAR), 6) AS [NormalizedMinTime],  
  right('000000'+cast((max(shiftedCardEventTime) % 240000) AS VARCHAR), 6) AS [NormalizedMaxTime]
FROM cteTbl
GROUP BY 
  CardNo, 
  ShiftedCardEventDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Date formatting in a query seems to be implementation specific.

Right SQLServer2000, You want to make your query to use the dates as dates - not as numbers. You really should have a single field that is a 'datetime' type, and not two separate fields.  But if you don't have control over this, then you'll need to do some datetime addition.  I'll pull up an example.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE
  (DATEDIFF(dd, GetDate(), CARDEVENTDATE) = 1  AND  CARDEVENTTIME > 030001 )  OR
  (DATEDIFF(dd, GetDate(), CARDEVENTDATE) = 0  AND  CARDEVENTTIME < 030000 )
```

Comment: he's using (ms)sql server 2000 (as mentioned in the post)

Answer (score 0):

This would be incorrect because the condition will always be false: (you're storing your date as an integer instead of a datetime, and an integer has no way of knowing it should wrap around at midnight)

```
Select Cardno, Cardeventdate, Min(cardeventtime), 
  max(cardeventtime) from table where Cardeventtime >030001 
      and Cardeventtime < 030000
```

The query should be written like this instead:

```
Select Cardno, Cardeventdate, Min(cardeventtime), 
  max(cardeventtime) from table where (Cardeventtime between 030001 and 120000)
      OR (cardeventtime between 000000 and 030000)
```

Once you factor this into your other queries, you should be able to come up with a solution.

Edit: sorry, meant OR instead of AND in the query.

Comment: WHERE(Cardeventtime between 030001 and 120000) - BUT HOW IT WILL TAKE A PREVIOUS DAY DATA'S
AND (cardeventtime between 000000 and 030000) - IS TODAY OK

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you just call:

```
select *
from someTable
where cardeventtime not between 30000 and 30001
order by cardeventdate, cardeventtime
```

Comment: Cardeventtime seems to be an integer. A value of 4 AM, which falls between 3 AM of a day, and 3 AM of the following day would have a value of 40000 given the data model. This does not fall between 30000 and 30001, so your example is incorrect. Actually, between is exclusive, so your condition will never match anything.

Answer (score 0):

The script is SQLServer2005 but using #Temp tables, you should be able to convert it to a usable SQLServer2000 script.

If I understand you correctly, following script groups the records by *dd 03:00:00* - *dd+1 
03:00:00*

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
  CARDEVENTDATE INTEGER
  , CARDEVENTTIME INTEGER
  , CARDNO INTEGER)

DECLARE @TableDateTime TABLE (
  CARDEVENTDATETIME DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (20090224,92007,485)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (20090224,92345,321)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (20090225,163932,168)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (20090225,164630,471)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (20090225,165027,488)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (20090225,165137,247)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (20090225,165147,519)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (20090225,165715,518)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (20090225,165749,331)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (20090303,162059,240)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (20090303,162723,518)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (20090303,155029,386)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (20090303,155707,441)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (20090303,162824,331)

INSERT INTO @TableDateTime
SELECT 
  [DATETIME-3] = 
    DATEADD(MONTH, ((CARDEVENTDATE/10000-1900)*12)+(CARDEVENTDATE/100)%100-1, CARDEVENTDATE%100-1) 
    + DATEADD(SS, (((CARDEVENTTIME/10000)-3)*3600)+(((CARDEVENTTIME/100)%100)*60)+CARDEVENTTIME%100, 0)
FROM @Table

SELECT CAST(CAST(tdt1.CARDEVENTDATETIME-1 AS INTEGER) AS DATETIME), COUNT(*)
FROM @TableDateTime tdt1
GROUP BY CAST(tdt1.CARDEVENTDATETIME-1 AS INTEGER)

/*
  What do all the casts, div's and mods mean
*/
SELECT
  /* Split */
  [YEAR] = CARDEVENTDATE / 10000
  , [MONTH] = (CARDEVENTDATE / 100) % 100
  , [DAY] = CARDEVENTDATE % 100
  , [HOUR] = CARDEVENTTIME / 10000  
  , [MINUTE] = (CARDEVENTTIME / 100) % 100
  , [SECOND] = CARDEVENTTIME % 100  
  /* Date & Time */
  , [DATE] = DATEADD(MONTH, ((CARDEVENTDATE/10000-1900)*12)+(CARDEVENTDATE/100)%100-1, CARDEVENTDATE%100-1)
  , [TIME] = DATEADD(SS, (CARDEVENTTIME/10000*3600)+(((CARDEVENTTIME/100)%100)*60)+CARDEVENTTIME%100, 0)
  /* DateTime */
  , [DATETIME] = 
      DATEADD(MONTH, ((CARDEVENTDATE/10000-1900)*12)+(CARDEVENTDATE/100)%100-1, CARDEVENTDATE%100-1)
      + DATEADD(SS, (CARDEVENTTIME/10000*3600)+(((CARDEVENTTIME/100)%100)*60)+CARDEVENTTIME%100, 0)
  , [DATETIME-3] = 
      DATEADD(MONTH, ((CARDEVENTDATE/10000-1900)*12)+(CARDEVENTDATE/100)%100-1, CARDEVENTDATE%100-1) 
      + DATEADD(SS, (((CARDEVENTTIME/10000)-3)*3600)+(((CARDEVENTTIME/100)%100)*60)+CARDEVENTTIME%100, 0)
FROM @Table
ORDER BY [DATETIME]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

First put both columns with date and time together in one column (i.e. `carddate`) of type `datetime`.

**Step 2**
If you want to do grouping based on some split time during the day do something like this (split time in example 3 AM):

```
select min(carddate) as Minimum, max(carddate) as Maximum
from sampleTable
group by
    year(dateadd(hour, -3, carddate)),
    month(dateadd(hour, -3, carddate)),
    day(dateadd(hour, -3, carddate))
```

But you won't be able to get card numbers within groups as simple as this. You'll have to use user function for that kind of functionality

Answer (score 0):

Solution using just a query:

```
SELECT  CardEventDate, CardEventTime, CardNo
        ,(1000000*CAST(CardEventDate AS BIGINT) + CAST(CardEventTime AS BIGINT)) AS CardEventDateTimeINT
        ,((1000000*CAST(CardEventDate AS BIGINT) + CAST(CardEventTime AS BIGINT))-150000)/1000000 AS StartDate
FROM    "table"
WHERE   ((1000000*CAST(CardEventDate AS BIGINT) + CAST(CardEventTime AS BIGINT))-150000)/1000000 = '20090223'
```

The parameters are:

- '20090223' - the start date for your 24h period (your filter)
- 150000 in the WHERE clause is representing start time of 15:00:00. Changing it will give you different 24h ranges. You may want it to be 150001, if exact time should go to another date.

  - Removing the filter (WHERE clause) will give you all results, which you can further filter later if you uncomment a column 'StartDate'

The way it is implemented is by composing a DATETIME from your date and time, but using not a DATETIME data type, but just a BIGINT, so that value of 20090224092007 would be date of 20090224 and time of 092007. Most important thing is that it is still sortable and it is easy to cut off/shift buy just using the INTEGER division. That is what I do buy substracting 150000 (time 15:00:00).

The result (with filter as in query above) is:

```
CardEventDate CardEventTime CardNo CardEventDateTimeINT StartDate
------------- ------------- ------ -------------------- --------------------
20090224      92007         485    20090224092007       20090223
20090224      92345         321    20090224092345       20090223
```

The result without any filter is below, so that you can filter by StartDate later:

```
CardEventDate CardEventTime CardNo CardEventDateTimeINT StartDate
------------- ------------- ------ -------------------- --------------------
20090224      92007         485    20090224092007       20090223
20090224      92345         321    20090224092345       20090223
20090225      163932        168    20090225163932       20090225
20090225      164630        471    20090225164630       20090225
20090225      165027        488    20090225165027       20090225
20090225      165137        247    20090225165137       20090225
20090225      165147        519    20090225165147       20090225
20090225      165715        518    20090225165715       20090225
20090225      165749        331    20090225165749       20090225
20090303      162059        240    20090303162059       20090303
20090303      162723        518    20090303162723       20090303
20090303      155029        386    20090303155029       20090303
20090303      155707        441    20090303155707       20090303
20090303      162824        331    20090303162824       20090303
```

This is the version with GROUP BY, MIN(..) and MAX(..):

```
SELECT  CardNo, 
        ((1000000*CAST(CardEventDate AS BIGINT) + CAST(CardEventTime AS BIGINT))-30000)/1000000 AS CardEvenDateAdjusted, 
        MIN(CardEventTime) AS MinTime, 
        MAX(CardEventTime) AS MaxTime
        --,COUNT(*) AS NUM
FROM    "table"
GROUP BY CardNo, ((1000000*CAST(CardEventDate AS BIGINT) + CAST(CardEventTime AS BIGINT))-30000)/1000000
```

Note few things:

- CardEvenDateAdjusted will not be exactly correct for those between 00:00:00 and 03:00:00 of the next day
- MinTime which is less then 030000 will mean that it is actually of the next day, so in fact it is not really a MIN...
- If your CardEventTime is sting (not integer), then you must ensure that it has leading zeros (020000, not 20000), otherwise the MIN, MAX will not sort it properly, so that 20000 is higher then 150000.

**Again: unless you re-ask a GOOD question, you will NOT get an answer you are looking for.**

Comment: @Jash: what do you mean "tool long error"? Do you get an error when executing this query? What kind of error?

Comment: Hi van, 

CAST(((1000000 * CAST(CardEventDate AS DECIMAL(9, 0)) + CAST([table].CardEventTime AS DECIMAL(9, 0))) - 150000) / 1000000 AS INT) AS StartDate

Not clear with this line, can you explain this query. please.

Comment: @Jash: added explanation in the answer. And changed DECIMAL to BIGINT for better clarity.
This very line composes datetime (kind-of) from your date and time fields, then subtracts the offset time (which is 15:00:00) using -150000. and the INTEGER! division by 1000000 is to cut off time from this datetime, so that we have just date for easy filtering. This is start date of the range.

Comment: 15:00:00 is PM, But i need yesterday morning 03:00:01 am  to today morning 03:00:00 AM DATA'S, SO CAN I PUT 03:00:00 INSTEAD OF 15:00:00 In your mentioned query

Comment: Exactly. Instead of 150000 use 30000.

Comment: query:

where date between startdate and enddate and time between 030001 and 030000 

030001 is yesteday date time, 
so query like - where time beween 030001 (how it will goes to yesteday because we mentioned only a time in where condtion not mentioned a date. How?

Comment: cardno is an separate table, carddate, cardtime is an separate table
I used your query, but it is asking group by clause. so i put
group by cardtime.  
but i can't able to get max(time) of the carddate.

Comment: Jash. You wrote you have 1 table with sample data. Why do not you provide the *real* data structure you have, sample data, and the result you want.

Comment: Van:  Below i mentioned the correct table and query. Go throgh and please give some idea's - jash.

Comment: Van: Date is displaying correctly, but how to get a min(time) of previous day > 03:00:01 am and max(time) of today < 03:00:00 am 
Query Help?

Comment: Van: For Your query date is displaying correctly but how to get min(time) and Max(time)

Comment: How to Get Min(time) and Max(time) for the Particular date - urgent

Comment: First of all I suggest you create another question for this. It is simple and people really do not need to read all conversation here to answer it. Then: if any answer is good enough for you, you should mark it as accepted.